# Store points by x, y and multiple z

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, store

I will write an example so you can understand me :

For instance, I have these 3 points : (0, 1, 244) - (0, 1, 255) - (1, 2, 133)

Actually I need to average the Z when 2 points have the same (x, y). My idea is to store them in something (an array, a dictionary ?) with a double index/key where the value is an array of the Z.

So I basically want to have this : [0, 1, [244, 255]] and [1, 2, [133]]

My problem is I don't know what to use to store them the simpliest way to do so...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: double index key is not possible.

Comment: I figured it out :/ Do you have an other idea ? I need to find the Z of a given couple of (x, y) basically

Comment: you can store the data in x --> y --> [z1, z2 ] way. I can help you with the code if you can show me your input data format.

Comment: a dict of dicts storing lists: `{0:{1:[244,255]}, 1:{2:[133,]}}`. as long as you only use integers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples can be dictionary keys:

```
myDict = {(1,2): 3}
```

is perfectly valid.

Another approach would be to use `itertools.groupby`, but make sure that your list is already sorted by they key you want to use for your groups (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

myList = [(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4)]
for grp, values in groupby(myList, lambda x: (x[:2])):
   print(grp, list(values))
```

Comment: I tried your code with that list : myList = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (5, 6, 7), (5, 7, 8), (5, 6, 9)]

But I got :
((1, 2), [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4)])
((5, 6), [(5, 6, 7)])
((5, 7), [(5, 7, 8)])
((5, 6), [(5, 6, 9)])
It only works when the same (x, y) points are following each other :/

Comment: Solved by doing myList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0,1)) !

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that the list should be sorted on the key: "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary:

```
points = [(0, 1, 244), (0, 1, 255), (1, 2, 133)]
d = {}
for point in points:
    key = point[:2]
    if key in d.keys():
        (d[key]).append(point[2])
    else:
        d[key] = [point[2]]
print(d)
```

For the mean values:

```
import numpy as np
for k in d.values():
    print(np.mean(k))
```

Comment: You can just do `sum(lst) / len(lst)` without using numpy

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. As Geotop suggested, use a dictionary indexed with a tuple.
   This according to me is an elegant solution.
2. Depending on the purpose and ease of traverse, you may convert the same to a nested list as follows:

   a = [ [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ],
         [ [123,234,345], [567,678,543], [433,645,754] ] ]

Now you may access the list of `z` values corresponding to `(x,y)` using `a[1][i]`, where the tuple `(x,y)` is stored as `a[0][i]`.

The second method seems much better to me as it avoids dictionary use and makes indexing much easier (as it is indexed with integers.). But at the end, it all depends on your purpose.

Storing it randomly in a list and getting the values by a search is a bad idea if you look up the data frequently or if the data is huge.